# CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set in docker container

Tags: docker, pytorch, dockerfile, containers

I have the following Dockerfile, trying to create a container that encapsulates CLIP-Fields github (https://github.com/notmahi/clip-fields):

```
# Use the official PyTorch base image with CUDA support
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.8.1-cuda11.1-cudnn8-runtime

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install g++ -y

# Clone the CLIP Fields repository
RUN git clone https://github.com/notmahi/clip-fields /clip-fields
WORKDIR /clip-fields

# Clone and install the Detic submodule
RUN git clone https://github.com/notmahi/Detic.git

# Clone and install the LSeg submodule
RUN git clone https://github.com/notmahi/LSeg.git

# Create a conda environment and activate it. py 3.8 used
RUN conda create -n cf python=3.8 && \ 
    echo "conda activate cf" >> ~/.bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

# Install dependencies
RUN conda install -y pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch-lts -c nvidia

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
# Set the working directory to the gridencoder folder
WORKDIR /clip-fields/gridencoder

# Install the hashgrid encoder with the relevant CUDA module
# Update the CUDA_HOME path if necessary
# ENV CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
# RUN apt-get install -y cuda-runtime-11-1
RUN python setup.py install

# Set the working directory back to the root of the CLIP Fields repository
WORKDIR /clip-fields

# Run any necessary commands or scripts here

# Set the command to run when the container starts
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

It crashes on  "> [13/14] RUN python setup.py install" with the following error:

```
0 0.181 mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device                                                                                                                            
#0 0.864 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                              
#0 0.864   File "setup.py", line 47, in <module>                                                                                                                                         
#0 0.864     CUDAExtension(
#0 0.864   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 867, in CUDAExtension
#0 0.864     library_dirs += library_paths(cuda=True)
#0 0.864   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 975, in library_paths
#0 0.864     if (not os.path.exists(_join_cuda_home(lib_dir)) and
#0 0.864   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1982, in _join_cuda_home
#0 0.864     raise EnvironmentError('CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. '
#0 0.864 OSError: CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. Please set it to your CUDA install root.
------
Dockerfile:35
--------------------
  33 |     # ENV CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
  34 |     # RUN apt-get install -y cuda-runtime-11-1
  35 | >>> RUN python setup.py install
  36 |     
  37 |     # Set the working directory back to the root of the CLIP Fields repository
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash --login -c python setup.py install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Does "FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.8.1-cuda11.1-cudnn8-runtime" contain CUDA and pytorch necessary? How can I set CUDA_HOME?

Comment: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-environment-variables

Comment: `# Update the CUDA_HOME path if necessary
# ENV CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda` did you update it?

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried that, but it appears an error that cuda was not there

Comment: @RobertCrovella Am I not following the documentation right? It is a ENV variable right? But I can't seme to find cuda in the container

Answer (score 0):

CUDA_HOME can not pass across the layers.
So you maybe need export the CUDA_HOME at the same line with `python install`